# Arquillian spring extension javaconfig is initializing context for each test

Tags: java, spring, junit, jboss-arquillian

I am trying to test some rest interfaces using Arquillian.
I have a class

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
@SpringAnnotationConfiguration(classes = PersistenceTestConfig.class)
public class RestTest{...}
```

In this clas i have a deployment method and several tests for now.
The deployment is shared for all tests but context is initialized for each
test.

I have tried with this `@ContextLifeCycle(ContextLifeCycleMode.TEST_CASE)` annotation but i'm facing the same issue.

How can i configure arquillian to use same context for all tests ?

Thank you

EDIT 1:

This happens all the time(each test):

```
2016-10-19 15:18:46 INFO  [anonymousUser] [127.0.0.1] AnnotationConfigApplicationContext:982 - Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@3c8d5c05: startup date [Wed Oct 19 15:18:46 EEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-10-19 15:18:46 INFO  [anonymousUser] [127.0.0.1] LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean:551 - Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'persistenceUnit'
2016-10-19 15:18:47 INFO  [anonymousUser] [127.0.0.1] AnnotationConfigApplicationContext:581 - Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@2c0a0685: startup date [Wed Oct 19 15:18:47 EEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-10-19 15:18:47 INFO  [anonymousUser] [127.0.0.1] AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor:155 - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2016-10-19 15:18:47 INFO  [anonymousUser] [127.0.0.1] PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker:328 - Bean 'persistenceTestConfig' of type [class de.awinta.licensing.server.core.config.PersistenceTestConfig] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-10-19 15:18:47 INFO  [anonymousUser] [127.0.0.1] AbstractJPAConfig:114 - [PERSISTENCE CONFIG] - Initialize Spring Bean: exceptionTranslation
2016-10-19 15:18:47 INFO  [anonymousUser] [127.0.0.1] AbstractJPAConfig:89 - [PERSISTENCE CONFIG] - Initialize Spring Bean: entityManagerFactory
2016-10-19 15:18:47 INFO  [anonymousUser] [127.0.0.1] AbstractJPAConfig:61 - [PERSISTENCE CONFIG] - Initialize Spring Bean: dataSource
2016-10-19 15:18:47 INFO  [anonymousUser] [127.0.0.1] LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean:334 - Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'persistenceUnit'
2016-10-19 15:18:47 INFO  [anonymousUser] [127.0.0.1] LogHelper:46 - HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: persistenceUnit
    ...]
2016-10-19 15:18:47 INFO  [anonymousUser] [127.0.0.1] AbstractPoolBackedDataSource:522 - Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [ acquireIncrement -> 10, acquireRetryAttempts -> 10, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 3000, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, dataSourceName -> 1hge7xl9j1paaqpcnkbsaf|1cb8ec46, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, description -> null, driverClass -> org.h2.Driver, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, identityToken -> 1hge7xl9j1paaqpcnkbsaf|1cb8ec46, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 3000, initialPoolSize -> 3, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:h2:mem:arquillian, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 0, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 100, maxStatements -> 1000, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 10, numHelperThreads -> 3, preferredTestQuery -> null, properties -> {user=******, password=******}, propertyCycle -> 0, statementCacheNumDeferredCloseThreads -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, userOverrides -> {}, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false ]
2016-10-19 15:18:47 INFO  [anonymousUser] [127.0.0.1] Dialect:145 - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2016-10-19 15:18:47 INFO  [anonymousUser] [127.0.0.1] LobCreatorBuilder:123 - HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
2016-10-19 15:18:47 INFO  [anonymousUser] [127.0.0.1] ASTQueryTranslatorFactory:47 - HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2016-10-19 15:18:47 INFO  [anonymousUser] [127.0.0.1] SchemaUpdate:207 - HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
2016-10-19 15:18:47 INFO  [anonymousUser] [127.0.0.1] SchemaUpdate:218 - HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
2016-10-19 15:18:47 INFO  [anonymousUser] [127.0.0.1] SchemaUpdate:230 - HHH000396: Updating schema
2016-10-19 15:18:47 INFO  [anonymousUser] [127.0.0.1] TableMetadata:65 - HHH000261: Table found: ARQUILLIAN.PUBLIC.LS_DB_UPDATE
2016-10-19 15:18:47 INFO  [anonymousUser] [127.0.0.1] TableMetadata:66 - HHH000037: Columns: [id, last_modified_time, update_file, run_date, created_time]
```

Quote from Arquillian website:

> Previous versions had one common drawback, each test were running
>   using a separate instance of Spring’s ApplicationContext. Although the
>   ApplicationContext were destroyed and all of its resources were freed
>   after the test execution, this brought additional overhead for each
>   test. From now on the developer has the control whether he want to
>   create only a single context per test case or to have each test run
>   with a new “clean” context, which in some situation might be handy. By
>   default the context will be created only once, but it can easly be
>   changed by adding the @ContextLifeCycle annotation to the test case.

What i am doing wrong ?

Comment: are you sure it indeed gets initialized each time and not taken from cache?

Comment: it runs persistence init each time,first time it creates tables,and then runs update schema.